# Dart need to filter array by pricing between

Tags: flutter, dart

I have simple data like this

```
{ID: 1195, SubCategoryID: 87, Name: Fajita Pizza (S), Price: 199.0}, {ID: 1195, SubCategoryID: 87, Name: Fajita Pizza (S), Price: 299.0}
```

I am using RangeSlider to get the range of user

```
              RangeSlider(
                values: _currentRangeValues,
                min: 1,
                max: 10000,
                divisions: 100,
                labels: RangeLabels(
                  _currentRangeValues.start.round().toString(),
                  _currentRangeValues.end.round().toString(),
                ),
                onChanged: (RangeValues values) {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentRangeValues = values;
                    print(_currentRangeValues);
                  });
                },
              ),
```

The range is printing like this `RangeValues(1.0, 8400.16)` I need to filter this range with my Data. So ill get that product in an array whose price is between RangeValues

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are intending to do, but as @pskink says, you can use List.where to filter your list of products by range:

```
double minPrice = 200;
double maxPrice = 300;
filteredProducts = products.where((element) {
  return (element["Price"]>minPrice && element["Price"]<maxPrice);
}).toList();
log(filteredProducts.toString());
```